# Recordset.find bof and eof both is false even when no record is present

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use ADODB recordset.find method to check to see if a record is present and add it if it is not present and do other stuff if it is present. I simplified my current code but it looks something like this:

```
     Do While Not (myValue < 4000)
            If Not (rstLocalItems.BOF) Then
                rstLocalItems.MoveFirst
            End If
            rstLocalItems.Find "ItemNo='" & myVal & "'"
            If rstLocalItems.EOF = True or rstLocalItems.BOF = True  Then


            Else

            'This value already exists do other stuff
             
             End if
             myValue = myValue + 1
Loop
```

When the value is not found I am inserting the value into a local table which I am clearing out completely right now which means no values should be found. When the loop is at `35` for example I have all the values from 1-34 I can see in the table. But when it as 35 it says that both EOF and BOF is false. I am searching for 35 in the table the table only has value till 34 so EOF should return true.

Also, when I print the value of rstLocalItems("myVal") it says 34 when my debugger is at line:

```
If rstLocalItems.EOF = True or rstLocalItems.BOF = True  Then
```

This is kind of weird because it should say 1 at least because `rstLocalItems.MoveFirst` fires when right before the line above when I step through the code.

For some reason when I set the recordset to movefirst and search for 35. The code thinks that '34' is equal to '35' and moves the cursor to position containing the value '34'.

Can someone help me on why this might be happening?

Comment: I prefer DAO FindFirst. I've never used ADO Find. Could use DLookup() domain aggregate function just to check if a value already exists in table. No need to open a recordset.

Comment: Is ItemNo a text or number field? If it is number type, should not use apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: You have variables myVal and myValue - why? Should have `Option Explicit` in every module header. Is myVal also a field in table?

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the *BOF* check. Also, *ItemNo* is probably not *text*:

```
Do While myValue < 4000
    rstLocalItems.MoveFirst
    rstLocalItems.Find "ItemNo = " & myVal & ""
    If rstLocalItems.EOF = True Then
        ' No match.
    Else
        ' This value already exists do other stuff
    End if
    myValue = myValue + 1
Loop
```